# How to replace the link of Contact Us button of topmenu (website)

Tags: xpath, menu, odoo

I am trying to replace the link of Contact Us from `/page/contactus` to `#contact` in the website. But it added a new menu item.

[image]

This is what I did using xpath:

```
<template id="contactus_custom" customize_show="True" inherit_id="website.layout" name="Custom Contact Us">
    <xpath expr="//*[@id='top_menu']/li" position="replace">
        <li>
            <a t-attf-href="#contact">
                Contact us
            </a>
        </li>
    </xpath>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The top menus in odoo website are dynamically defined, you can change the link from  the configuration menu, by following these steps:

1. [Activate debug mode](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/14.0/general/developer_mode/activate.html)
2. Then go to Website app, Configuration > Menus
3. Select the menu and update the URL